# How do I download an older OSX / macos version from the mac app store?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to test my mac app under OSX El Capitan 10.11 and OSX Yosemite 10.10 , and am currently running macos Sierra 10.12. So far I've tried searching under the app store but none of the older version appear when searching. Also have tried checking the apple developer downloads section https://developer.apple.com/download/ , as well as the 'more downloads' section there.

Are there any options besides attempting to download a torrent of the older OS?

Comment: old versions may not be signed, therefor you may not be able to install the versions you are after.

Comment: @OzzieSpin this is only true for iOS, not MacOS.

Comment: hmm, fair enough, I will delete my comment to prevent any confusion?

Answer (score 2):

If you've been using a mac long enough to have the desired older osx/macos versions installed under your apple id / itunes account, you can find these downloads by opening up the app store, then option-clicking the purchased tab. See picture below:

[image]

Answer found via Paul Goracke (@pgor)